# WHy my autocomplete is not suggesting anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

This is my php file. I want autosuggest for my text box which is not working. I have 3-4 sources of autosuggest.

```
<?php
$con =mysqli_connect("due connectn attributes");
$return_arr = array();
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["term"]);   
if (!$search) return;
$sql = "SELECT PName, PNo FROM PlayerDetails WHERE PName LIKE '%$search%'";
$sql = mysqli_query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $row_array['PNo'] = $row['PNo'];
    $row_array['PName'] = $row['PName'];
    //echo "$PName|$PNo\n";

            array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
            /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
            echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

The javascript part:

```
 <script src="/_js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/_js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#auto").autocomplete({
            source: "../_php/search.php",
            autoFocus:true
            }
        });
      });   //end READY

 </script>
```

The HTML part is:

```
  <p>
    <label for="Username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text"  name="auto" id="auto">
</p>
```

Comment: What is the error you getting in the console ?

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '../_php/search.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-5.3.29/share/pear')

Comment: So you path is wrong `../_php/search.php` Can you check whether the `search.php` is at the folder that is above the `_php` folder ?

Comment: You can try with js array as source. Just echo the results seperated by commas and then split them with js and assign it to an array. Refer that array as source. Like this:
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: yes
THE CONSOLE IS not showing any errors now just changed inverted commas
But the working is not happening

Comment: Changed the JS CODE To now from that site still nothing happened . Can please solve this puzle.

    $("#auto").autocomplete({
                 source: "../_php/search.php",
     minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
log( ui.item ?
    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
    }
                });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot generate *multiple* JSON encodes; that gets you no valid JSON, and jQuery will ignore it.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $row_array['PNo'] = $row['PNo'];
    $row_array['PName'] = $row['PName'];
    array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

}

The `echo json_encode($return_arr);` must happen only once *after* the `mysqli_close`:

```
    array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
```

}
   /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
   echo json_encode($return_arr);

Also, just in case, output the JSON content-type headers:

```
}
/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
Header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
die(json_encode($return_arr));
```

Lastly, you report this error in your comment:

```
<b>Warning</b>: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '../_php/search.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-5.3.29/share/pear')
```

This error can be caused by one thing only: you must be **including from PHP** the `search.php` script. I.e. in some of your PHP scripts there is a

```
include '../_php/search.php';
```

This must not be done - `search.php` must be an independent PHP script and it should return a valid JSON if you call its URL from a browser like this:

```
http://<yoursite>/_php/search.php?term=%
```

i.e., it should return something like

```
[["PnoNumber1":"PNameNumber1"],["PnoNumber2":"PNameNumber2"]]
```

## File organization (there's more than one way to do it)

The HTML file can be wherever you want, let's say it is in /_html/page.html

This file includes the necessary JS code which lives in /_js, so /_js/jquery.min.js and so on.

The PHP is called by the Javascript code inside the HTML as is detailed in another answer. When you include the 'search.php' URL in your Javascript, this generates a **new browser call** which has a lifecycle of its own in AJAX. This call must be able to "live" by itself, so it must work also if you use it in your browser's address bar. Otherwise it will not work in the script either.

So to test that the script is working (of course you can also use tools such as Firebug) you can invoke it from the browser:

```
http://<yoursite>/_php/search.php?term=%
```

The script must then connect to the database and perform the query, returning a valid JSON in the format that Autocomplete expects. So in answer to the call above you must see a valid JSON in the browser window.

The .autocomplete function is correctly bound with $('#auto') and the input field has indeed an id of 'auto'. So the call will be generated. The URI you put in the javascript must be valid **with reference to the javascript**, so if the form lives in /_html/searchpage.html, and the script in /_php/search.php, the relative URI will be ../_php/search.php (of course if the form is in /_html/forms/search.html, you will need ../../_php/search.php and so on).

Comment: i CANNOT understand this. You meant to say that search.php should be placed in the same folder where the html file is .

     For this error to be generated, you must be including from PHP the search.php script. This must not be done - search.php must be an independent PHP script and it should return a valid JSON if you call its URL like this:

    /_php/search.php?term=%

is this the path after typing some characters or place this path in javascript.

Comment: No you are not at all bad in  english. please answer my above query for path

Comment: Your search.php can be wherever you want. /_php/search.php is good. The PHP error you note means that **some other script** is including search.php, but this is not needed, and it should not be done. I'll edit the answer

Comment: after trying in browser
the error is 
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in mysite/_php/search.php on line 11

Comment: You have to pass the connection link too. Check out the manual for the mysqli escape string function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: "../_php/search.php",
        autoFocus:true
     }); //<----should be closed like this.
});
```

Comment: I did that but nothing happened.  If you have another way doing autosuggest please tell me. I have problem in understanding PDO php codes.